# ejabberd hook execution error while trying building a message receipts module

Tags: module, ejabberd

I am getting an error while trying to return a receipt message from server to acknowledge  message received at server for which I am using a non official  module (`mod_stanza_ack`) and ejabberd 15.07.

I have compiled and configured it successfully too, but it's giving the following error during ejabberd hook execution:

```
@ejabberd_hooks:run_fold1:371 {undef,[{mod_send_receipt,on_user_send_packet,[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"6uAAO-218">>}.....
```

Answer (score 0):

`undef` means the function `mod_send_receipt:on_user_send_packet`.

I see possible reason for this:

- source file is not compiled (due to syntax error for example)
- or the resulting .beam file is not in your Erlang VM code path
- or the function is actually not defined in your module

You need to fix your module accordingly or put the .beam file in the right place.